# Nativescript Angular emulator not refreshing with tns run ios

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

I have trouble determining why my iOS emulator is not updating in real time as I update my code. Each time I make changes, the terminal registers the updates, however the emulator doesn't refresh the view. This is my console output:

```
Compilation complete. Watching for files changes.
File Change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

If anybody could please point me in the direction of this issue, that would be superb as there isn't much else to go by on any other forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when running the application from a file path which contained a space, the real time updates had trouble. After ensuring all directories within the project absolute path contained no spaces, the livereload worked.

Answer (score -2):

You need to be more clear on what you did to "not work".

Here's how I do it to make things livereload.

`tns run ios`
If I do above without a device plugged in, it automatically uses the Emulator. If I have a device plugged in, it uses the device.

Livereload works for both instances, such as when I add things to the template.